# handle .cst file with python urllib/httplib

Tags: python, cgi, urllib

I want to connect to a web appliance via a ".cst" file. If you want to open it in Browser yu have to type

```
http://x.x.x.x/index.cst?Lang=en&login=blafoo&passwd=foobla
```

How can i send this request with urllib or some other package?

Tanks for Help

Basti

Comment: Have you tried? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'Lang': 'en', 'login': 'blafoo', 'passwd': 'foobla'})
f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://x.x.x.x/index.cst?%s" % params)
f.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

With `urllib`:

```
import urllib

site = urllib.urlopen('http://x.x.x.x/index.cst?Lang=en&login=blafoo&passwd=foobla')
data = site.read()
```

This script's variable `data` will store contents of what you've got from URL you passed (response body).

Answer (score 1):

i recommend using [requests](http://python-requests.org) (all the cool kids use it! ;), although an answer using `urllib` has been given. with requests:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://x.x.x.x/index.cst?Lang=en&login=blafoo&passwd=foobla')
# response.text contains the response contents
# response.status_code gives the response status code (200, 201, 404, etc)
```

for extra credit:

```
import requests
data = {'Lang': 'en', 'login': 'blafoo', 'passwd': 'foobla'}
response = requests.get('http://x.x.x.x/index.cst', params=data)
```